# Using a scanner to get answer from user, to then compare result with arraylist.

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to create a program in java to get an answer from a user using a scanner, this result should then be compared to an arraylist of numbers, ie a multiple choice question, and then print out a string. I can get the value in the arraylist to compare to value and print, but when inputting the scanner answer nothing happens.

cheers

```
'public static void main (String [] args){
    ArrayList<String> answersArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    answersArray.add("4");
    answersArray.add("5");
    answersArray.add("10");
    answersArray.add("20");

    System.out.println("Please select the answer from the list below\n" + answersArray);

    Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value = ExamQuestionSimpleChoice.answer;

    if   ( value == (answersArray.get(0))){
    System.out.println("This answer is correct, you gained:  "  );
    }
    }

    public static String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public static void setValue(String value) {
    ExamQuestionSimpleChoice.value = value;
}`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating the scanner will just prepare the scanner object. You need to call answer.readLine() and store that in a string variable.

Then you will need to loop through the arraylist and compare that to the value you stored from the scanner.

Comment: Thanks this in combination with Kamyar's answer sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of setter and getter for a local inaccessible variable?

as James mentioned you need to read the input string with Scanner object by calling the `.nextLine()` not just compare the whole scanner object with target. Next, you need to replace the `==` with `.equals(answersArray.get(0))` and it'll work

Comment: Cheers, helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add answer.next() to take the input from the keyboard! You are just initializing but not giving reference.